# Unable to run regex on file content after putting it?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have created a simple class to handle opening, reading, and closing a file. In addition, I would like to run a regex on its contents to find a 4 digit date. However, when I run my code I get the following error:

```
file_class.rb:17:in `find_date': undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from file_class.rb:24:in `<main>'
```

This error only occurs if I run the `read_file` method before it, which simply puts the file contents. I am not sure why doing so would result in such an error.

Below is my code:

```
class MyFile
  attr_reader :handle

  def initialize(filename)
    @handle = File.open(filename)
  end

  def read_file
    puts @handle.gets
  end

  def finished
    @handle.close
  end

  def find_date
    matching = @handle.gets.match(/\d{4}/)
    puts matching[0]
  end
end

f = MyFile.new('text.txt')
f.read_file
f.find_date
f.finished
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your file had a single line of contents.

When you call `gets` on an open file handle, the handle returns the line it is currently looking at and moves its "cursor" down to the next line. After you've read the last line, `gets` will return `nil`.

Your class would be better (for a few reasons) if you read the file once and cache the contents, rather than caching the handle and attempting to read several times:

```
class MyFile
  attr_reader :contents

  def initialize(filename)
    File.open(filename) do |f|
      @contents = f.read
    end
  end

  def find_date
    matching = @contents.match(/\d{4}/)
    puts matching[0]
  end
end
```

This approach is better because:

- You only need to read the file once.
- You're reading the whole file at once, not one line at a time (`File#read` instead of `File#gets`).
- Your class has better *encapsulation* - other code that wants to use it doesn't need to tell your class to read the file, then find a date, then close the file - all of the logic is internal to your class.
- You need to write less code - `attr_accessor` makes `contents` available to calling code without you needing to write your own methods. This is good because it's quicker to write and, much more importantly, it's clearer to read.